# Using from in eloquent query

Tags: php, laravel

I am using `Laravel Framework 6.16.0`:

As I am adding my connection to my DB object I cannot select the table to join on.

```
            $symbol = DB::connection('mysql_prod')->select('companies') // "companies" is the table
                ->join('insider_transaction', 'insider_transaction.companies_id', '=', 'companies.id')
                ->join('persons', 'persons.id', '=', 'insider_transaction.persons_id')
                ->where('insider_transaction.transaction_date', '>=', Carbon::today()->subDays(3)->startOfDay())
                ->orderBy('transaction_date', 'desc')
                ->distinct()->get('symbol');
```

Before I coded, `DB::table('companies')`, as I using now the `DB::connection(...)` I am wondering how to add the selected table to my eloquent query.

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: as u r doing join you should select like `->select('companies.*')`

Comment: what is wrong with: DB::connection('mysql_prod')->table('companies')->join ...... ->select(''symbol')

Answer (score 1):

try this i added `table('companies')->select('companies.*')`

```php
  $symbol = DB::connection('mysql_prod')->table('companies')->select('companies.*') // "companies" is the table
            ->join('insider_transaction', 'insider_transaction.companies_id', '=', 'companies.id')
            ->join('persons', 'persons.id', '=', 'insider_transaction.persons_id')
            ->where('insider_transaction.transaction_date', '>=', Carbon::today()->subDays(3)->startOfDay())
            ->orderBy('transaction_date', 'desc')
            ->distinct()
            ->get('symbol');
```